# Issue with Spotify Iframes in client vs server side instances

Tags: iframe, spotify, spotify-app

I am having an issue with Spotify Iframes displaying tracks in preview mode. According to [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2018/07/19/new-updates-to-spotify-play-button/) for Full Track Playback in Iframes,

> We have introduced full playback directly inside of the Spotify Play Button. It works on most major browsers, including Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge. The user must also be logged into spotify.com in their web browser and your  HTML must contain the allow="encrypted-media" attribute.

Using the iframe script below (provided in each spotify track) or simply [accessing the embed URL](https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/2vWE6Btt6Kwc8yRkr6g4Qg?utm_source=generator), I get access to the full track in my browser when I am logged into my web-based Spotify account. However, when deployed to a server ([such as an EC2 instance](http://ec2-3-101-152-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:81/)), I am stuck in preview mode while still being logged into my web-based spotify account. Similarly, I'm stuck in preview mode when deploying the same script in StackOverflow (see below to run code snippet)

Any idea what is going on? My understanding is the Iframes are Client-side generated, so if my browser is logged in to the web-based platform, I should have access right?

Any resources to help me further understand would be appreciated. Thank you!

```html
<iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/2vWE6Btt6Kwc8yRkr6g4Qg?utm_source=generator" width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```